# Why do I have to serialize user object properties with PassportJS for sessions?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Could anyone explain in detail, or at least reference a good explanation of how this works. Why do I have to serialize (byte stream) `user.id` or any prop of the user object for it to be stored as a cookie on the client?

```
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id], function (err, rows) {
            //verify callback invokes .done()
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to store the whole user object in ram when you may have 100's or more logged in users, so you only want to remember the minimal info to be able to **find** that info later if/when you need it. `serialize()` is how you decide what to keep in ram and `deserialize()` is how you get all the discarded data back later, when you need it.

I have commented your original code to illustrate.

```
// what minimal info can i record to look up this user later?
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) { 
    done(null, user.id); // a user id is enough. let's go with that.
});

// some user came back and they are making a request. All I have is this lousy ID. How do I look up the rest of the data I need?
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {

    // let's look them up in the database.
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id], function (err, rows) {
        //verify callback invokes .done()
        done(err, rows[0]); 
    });
});
```

All of the above just sets and reads from `res.session`. How sessions get saved or matched up to cookies is unrelated. Express-session is a common library to do that but there are others.

Comment: Ok, with all that middleware, how does the serialized user get passed on to `express-session` or `passport-session` to take on a life of a cookie? In the case of deserialization, is it the `cookie-parser` that passes the id to passport? How does it work?

Comment: It just saves to `res.session`. I added to the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you would serialize and deserialize a user object is so you don't have to keep track of the client's state (authenticated or not) while not having to put sensitive data (like password hashes or raw passwords) on the client's device. In addition, you don't have to transmit possibly sensitive data over a possibly non-secure connection. Even better, since the serialized data is only an id, it will mean less data to transmit.

In principle, you don't have to do it this way but most of the web application frameworks take this approach (Django's auth for [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/)). Passport is no exception.

The way this works, without going into how Passport actually functions, is that you have to keep account of the state of your application over a stateless protocol. The way to keep track of authentication, authorization, and identity is to send along some kind of token (like a user ID) to tell the server that I am who I say I am, saving me from logging in every time I make a request.

Now, as for Passport, the serialization procedure described in the [documentation](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/298d2452430dd0d1841d417e9c0d0b23e4b06239/lib/middleware/initialize.js#L7) makes some assertions on the pattern one could use to handle the creation of sessions. You can, however, have any procedure you like to handle the serialization, deserialization process. As pointed out in a comment, you wouldn't want to send the actual user ID down the wire - instead you should let your session middleware like [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) take care of the implementation logic.

Comment: User id is not exactly a good way to do this. A better way is to store session id. A session id is just a number that's unique to each browser connected to your server. Then store session data somewhere on the server (the best place is just a file, next best is database but a file is better). In the session data you associate the user id and logged in state - you don't expose this stuff to the client

Comment: serialize/deserialize have nothing to do with what goes to the client device.  they control what goes in the session storage. The session middleware controls what goes on the client device (often a cookie).

Comment: I appreciate your comment, however I don't think I made the assertion that serializing/deserializing directly maps to what is stored on a client device, but I do appreciate the clarification.